# Weebly HTML Customization

Tags: html, weebly

I've been using Weebly to create multiple websites for various reasons.  Being quite advanced in raw HTML, I've come to no avail with editing Weebly sites directly using HTML.  They offer HTML files to edit the style of a page (mostly CSS), but not the true content - like `<p></p>` tags.

Does anyone know any way to bypass these restrictions?

Comment: There is a button to open HTML and CSS. I am having problems getting weebly to accept script directly written into the html though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's called Embed Code*

Normally WYSIWYG editors will have some kind of source button however as you've noticed Weeby does not. The custom HTML button on Weeby is actually called [***Embed Code***](http://kb.weebly.com/custom-html.html) which many would assume this means iframes and YouTube/Vimeo embeds however this is the case. Using the embed code feature will allow you to edit and add custom HTML to your Weeby page.

Comment: Thanks. But in general, I can't edit some sections of the page still, but this is a good alternative for page content.

Comment: IF you can't edit some parts of the page then you are not using the custom html. You can not use say a picture button and then edit the `<img>` to whatever you like, you would need to use the custom html rather than the original tag. I believe what your looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: The custom HTML is quite finicky, but I guess it's my only option to achieve most customization. Thanks though.